# CORS error when using API from the client

Tags: shopify

my (test) shop does not support CORS and does not respond with appropriate headers, so requests like `GET http://jenkins-hauck12345.myshopify.com/admin/products.json` fail with an error saying `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jenkins-hauck12345.myshopify.com/admin/products.json. Origin http://myapp.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

any advice on how to make it work? use `myapp.example.com` as a proxy?

thanks!